# How to update pandas dataframe from the Netcdf file based on latitude , longitude

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-xarray, netcdf4

As a Newbie in python, i had a basic question and it looks not easy for me.

I had More than 10 Netcdf files in one folder and all of them had dimensions (Latitude, Longnitude)
    Latitude=1800
    Longitude=3600

I opened all the files using xrray mfdataset but don't know wheather it is correct or wrong.

```
import xarray as xr
aa=xr.open_mfdataset('Data/*.nc', concat_dim=None)
```

It shows all the variables from all Netcdf files and Dimension of each files correctly.
How to update the pandas data frame with Netcdf variable values using respective Latitude and Longnitude columns (another pandas dataframe)?

As a beginner i felt it hard and posting here. Any sample code would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance